# react passing function to child not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that passes a function to a child component, and I bind it to onClick. But when I click I get an error:

> this.props.beBad is not a function, this.props.beBad is not defined

it looks something like this:

```
var Dad = React.createClass({
  beBad: function(someInput) {
    alert('being bad ' + someInput);
  },
  render: function() {
    var Children = this.state.children.map(function(data, index) {
          return (
            <Child beBad={this.beBad} key={index}/>
          );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {Children}
            </div>      
        );
  });

var Child = React.createClass({
  beBad: function() {
   this.props.beBad('some input');
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
     <div onClick={this.beBad}>
       be bad
     </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure `this` is what you expect?

Comment: its a react component function so I think `this` should theoretically work right?

Comment: Is the error literally `this.props.function is not a function, this.props.function is not defined`? because the code you've put here would complain about `this.props.beBad`.

Comment: @N3dst4 no sorry, you're right, the error says `this.props.beBad`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like `this` is what you expect. When using `React.createClass`, React will autobind the correct `this` IFF the call is at the top level of the function, so in this case it will autobind correctly:

```
render: function() {
  return (
   <div onClick={this.beBad}> // autobound
     be bad
   </div>
  );
}
```

But not here:

```
var Children = this.state.children.map(function(data, index) {
  return (
    <Child beBad={this.beBad} key={index}/> // `this` is not what you expect
  );
});
return (
  <div>
    {Children}
  </div>
);
```

The reason is because `map` is creating a new scope, and `this` is no longer what you'd expect, and React can't autobind it for you. You need to pass `this` around explicitly:

```
var Children = this.state.children.map(function(data, index) {
  return (
    <Child beBad={this.beBad.bind(this)} key={index}/> // bind `this`
  );
}, this); // pass `this`
```

**Note:** Seeing the other response, it is possible that React autobinds it for you inside the map, but in general I wouldn't rely on autobinding, explicit wins over implicit. Plus if you ever write React with ES6 classes it doesn't do autobinding.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a problem with your this because you're on the "map scope".

Try to pass `this` to your map :

```
var Children = this.state.children.map(function(data, index) {
  return (
    <Child beBad={this.beBad} key={index}/>
  );
}, this);
```

For your information see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map